# "Cannot create folder s37 in folder" in Netbeans 8.2 and JDK 8

Tags: java, netbeans, warnings, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

I am getting this error saying **Can not create folder in

 s37 or s36 like this**. I have uninstalled JDK and NetBeans together and installed again. But seems like the problem is coming back again again! 
I really appreciate if someone has any good solution.

Here is a screenshot of the error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Can you describe what series of tasks to do before getting this error message?
Perhaps also consider changing text to non-bold.

Answer (score 2):

There is a NetBeans Bug Report related to your issue: "[Bug 269339 - Infinite pop ups: Cannot create folder s38 in folder /Users/33070/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.0.2/index](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269339)"

Based on comments in that bug report, the easiest approach to solving your problem is:

- Check whether your directory `/Users/kabir/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/index` exists, because if it doesn't that would explain the error messages.
- If it doesn't exist then manually create that directory to see if that resolves the issue.

If that doesn't work, or the directory already existed, then try deleting/recreating your cache directory. To do that:

- Determine you cache directory. You can get its full path by selecting `Help > About`, then looking for the **Cache directory** entry in the **About** window.
- Close NetBeans, delete that directory, then restart NetBeans.

If you are still stuck after that:

- Build your project to reproduce the problem.
- Open the NetBeans log file: `View > IDE Log`.
- Update your question by copying/pasting the recent content of that log file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments, I have just done it. Actually, there was no folder, so I created one. Basically, I have seen it earlier sometime it does come back and give the same error message. I will try to use NetBeans continuously to see if this error come back then I will update my feedback. Thanks

Comment: @KabirKhan That's good. The mystery remains on why you are getting this problem, but at least you have a workaround if you encounter the problem again.

Comment: This solution basically worked based on 24 hours activity. Thanks very much.